# Unbind and undelegate events to submit only one form

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, backbone.js

I have 3 tabs that I can switch between. For one of my tabs, I generate a form/view in Backbone that I can submit to my controller. The problem is that if I switch between tabs and click on the tab that generates the form and then click submit, I submit multiple AJAX calls to my controller.

```
    addPlace: function(e) {
      if(!this.isSearch){
        this.add = new add({
          model: this.model,
          attachPoint: this.$("div.addAPlaceForm")
        });
        $('.add_to_place').addClass("hidden");
        $('.matchingWrapper').addClass("hidden");
        this.add.render();
        this.add.on("place:selected", this.placeSelect, this);
        this.isSearch = true;
      } 
    }

    //this.add.render()
    render: function(e){
      this.$el.html(this.addPlaceForm({
        place: this.model
      }));  
      view.prototype.render.call(this);
  }
```

When the user switches to one of the other tabs that doesn't generate the form, it hits this function:

```
   addPlacebacklink: function(e) {
        this.add.undelegateEvents();
        this.add.unbind();

        $("div.addAPlaceForm").html("");
        this.isSearch = false;
    }
```

I have read that you're supposed to `unbind` and `undelegateEvents`, however, I still see multiple AJAX calls to my controller. How do I setup Backbone so that I can switch between tabs multiple time and still submit only one form?

Answer (score 0):

I actually refactored my code to check for this.add and hide the form when I switch tabs.

```
addPlace: function(e) {
  if(!this.add){
    this.add = new add({
      model: this.model,
      attachPoint: this.$("div.addAPlaceForm")
      this.add.render();
      this.add.on("place:selected", this.placeSelect, this);
    });
    this.$('.add_to_place').addClass("hidden");
    this.$('.matchingWrapper').addClass("hidden");
    this.$(".form-horizontal").removeClass("hidden");

  } 
}


addPlacebacklink: function(e) {
     this.$(".form-horizontal").addClass("hidden");
}
```